# How do I get all source files in VS22

Tags: c++, git, github, src, crypto++

I created a program in c++ using the CryptoPP library. The program compiled and runs fine. Now how can I move all nessecary files to src folder so it is compilable with one or 2 commands, It took so many steps to use the cryptopp in vs22, but when I put the project on github, how can they just git clone and build the program easily.

Comment: Many github projects use CMake which makes building much easier for those who understand CMake and allows the user to use the most popular compilers on most operating systems with no modification.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use [**`abdes/cryptopp-cmake`**](https://github.com/abdes/cryptopp-cmake), which contains CMake files for Wei Dai's Crypto++ (https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp) for those who use the library in **[Modern CMake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/)** projects.
That means CMake 3.11+ and maybe even CMake 3.24+.

> ### Standard usage
>
> - Get this project using your favorite method (clone as submodule, get with FetchContent, get with CPM...)
> - In your master CMakeLists.txt, add the following:
>
>   ```
>   add_subdirectory(xxxx)
>   # where xxx is the location where you put the cryptopp-cmake files
>   ```
>
> That's pretty much it. You'll be able to link against `cryptopp` or the scoped alias `cryptopp::cryptopp` and have `cmake` handle everything else for you.

You can see such a project as a test/example at [`abdes/cryptopp-cmake/test`](https://github.com/abdes/cryptopp-cmake/tree/master/test).